# Passing User-Defined Table type using FluentData

Tags: orm, fluentdata

I'm new to FluentData, and I would like to know if it's possible to pass a user-defined table type to a stored procedure using FluentData.

```
dbContext().Sql("MyStoredProcedureName")
.Parameter("MyUserDefinedTableType", DbTypes.???????)
```

Which `DataTypes` should i use? Or is it not supported?